# Bookmarklet to prevent auto-logout on website

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am working in a web application which automatically logs you out after a set amount of inactivity. I have no control over the application. The relevant code the application uses to logout is here:

```
var windoc = window.document;
var timeoutID;

function AlertUser() {
    var msg = 'Session expires in 90 seconds. Continue with this session?';
    var preConfirmTime = new Date();
    if (confirm(msg)) {
        var postConfirmTime = new Date();
        if (postConfirmTime.getTime() - preConfirmTime.getTime() > 90000) {
            alert('Sorry, your session has already expired.');
          window.location = '/Logout.aspx';
        } else {
           var img = new Image(1,1);
           img.src = '/Reconnect.aspx';
           timeoutID = window.setTimeout('AlertUser()','3510000'); 
        }
    } else {
      window.location = '/Logout.aspx';
    }
}

function ResetTimeout(delay) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout('AlertUser()', delay);
}

timeoutID = window.setTimeout('AlertUser()','3510000');
```

Since the logouts are really breaking my workflow, I would like to have a bookmarklet that confirms `OK` whenever the session is about the expire. I thought I might use

```
javascript:window.confirm = function(){return true;};
```

But this only runs when I click the bookmarklet. Is there any way to make it run in the active (IE 10) browser tab automatically (so also if I open a new tab with the application) and make it check continuously? By the way I can not install any browser extensions. The only way of interacting with webpages is via a bookmarklet.

Answer (score 1):

If you can install other programs locally, use a program like Charles Proxy (using its "Rewrite" tool) to make changes to the application as it's delivered to your browser. This rewrite rule can be specified to always apply to this application as long as Charles is open.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no credentials to install browser plugins or standalone applications. Hence the bookmarklet question :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing this is your problem:

1. You run the bookmarklet, it prevents logout on current page.
2. You right click or ctrl+click a link on the current page to open a new tab, and that new tab eventually logs you out.

Possible solution: In addition to current code, the bookmarklet also attaches a click event listener on every link in page. If the listener detects CTRL+click, it prevents the default action, does `window.open`, and then modifies the code in the new tab also.

To prevent the same problem in the current window when you reload or navigate within the same tab, the bookmaklet can open a small child window which monitors its `parent`. If the monitor detects that the parent is no longer properly modified, it can re-apply the code.

One thing that I wonder about is if your current solution will really work if you leave the page open for a long time with no activity. The server might have its own internal session timeout that happens regardless of what modification you make on the client side. If so, that could possibly be prevented with a timer that does a benign background page fetch via AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to the timeout. First is the `AlertUser` timeout which triggers after 58 minutes, 30 seconds. The second is the session timeout on the server which apparently can be refreshed by making a GET request to `/Reconnect.aspx`.

The `ResetTimeout` function gives us a clue on how to handle the `AlertUser` timeout but it doesn't handle the server-side session timeout. So, taking it as a starting point we can do this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);     // stop the AlertUser from happening
    var img = new Image(1,1);
    img.src = '/Reconnect.aspx'; // stop server session from expiring
},15*60*1000);
```

This should remove any and all timeouts. You may be thinking that we can probably do the `clearTimeout` outside the `setInterval` and you may be right. But there may be code on the page that resets the `AlertUser` timeout so doing it in the loop allows you to re-clear it just in case.

The `setInterval` runs every 15 minutes (15*60*1000) which is 4 times more often than the page timeout of 58 minutes. But just in case the page timeout value changes you can just change the 15 minutes to another number. Don't do it too often or the site may blacklist you for spamming it.

Also, the code above doesn't guard in case you accidentally load the bookmarklet twice. You can make it safer by first clearing any previous `setInterval`:

```
if (typeof anti_timeout != 'undefined') {
    clearInterval(anti_timeout);   // clear previous anti-timeout timer
}
anti_timeout = setInterval(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    var img = new Image(1,1);
    img.src = '/Reconnect.aspx';
},15*60*1000);
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question correctly. Your `window.confirm` code appears to be working but it doesn't refresh the server-side session. This solution refreshes server side session on the page it's running. So regardless of how many tabs you open as long as this is running the session will be refreshed. Just remember not to accidentally close the tab that this is running on.

Comment: It is very possible that going to `/Logout.aspx` will kill the server seesion. So, just keeping server session alive might not be enough for the scenario in his question: Open new tab > JS code timeout opens lout.aspx > server session is ended. He may need a way to ensure that no tab will ever timeout and send him to lougout.aspx. Furthermore, even if it doesn't end his session, having your tabs change while you aren't looking is also anti-productive.

Comment: My ´javascript:window.confirm = function(){return true;};´ works but should run continuously, checking continuously whether the confirm box is there or not and if it is, basically confirm it. My question would be how to continuously run this bookmarklet?

Comment: Without browser extensions you can't really do anything. You need to click the bookmarklet every time you navigate around the site. One convoluted solution is to write a proxy that modifies the site by injecting the script on every page. For that you can't do it in the browser but need to run a server instead - doable with free servers like Google or Amazon cloud servers but not trivial.